# Need advice on how to display the result on the frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Im a novice to python. Im trying to display the result of my code on the frame. Also, when a letter is picked from the Combobox in tabA1 it affect the results on tabA2. Im not sure how to go about fixing these issued. Any advice will be great.

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import ttk
import heapq


class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.create_widgets()
        self.trip = {}

    def create_widgets(self):
      self.notebook = Notebook()   # Widgets

      self.style = Style()
      self.style.configure('frame.TFrame', background='grey')
      self.frame = Frame( style='frame.TFrame')
      self.frame.place(height=40, width=70, x=158, y=109)
      self.frame.config()

      self.tabA = Frame(self.notebook)
      self.tabB = Frame(self.notebook)
      self.tab3 = Frame(self.notebook)

      self.mainA = Notebook(self.tabA)
      self.tabA1 = Frame(self.mainA)
      self.tabA2 = Frame(self.mainA)
      self.mainA.add(self.tabA1, text = "tabA1")
      self.mainA.add(self.tabA2, text = "tabA2")
      self.mainA.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
      self.notebook.add(self.tabA, text = "tabA")
      self.notebook.add(self.tabB,  text= "tabB")
      self.notebook.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

      self.combo1= ttk.Combobox(self.tabA1)
      self.combo1.node_id = 'start'
      self.combo1['values'] = ('a','b','w','x','y','z')
      self.combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.handler1)
      self.combo1.pack()

      self.combo2= ttk.Combobox(self.tabA1)
      self.combo2.node_id = 'end'
      self.combo2['values'] = ('a','b','w','x','y','z')
      self.combo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.handler2)
      self.combo2.pack()

      self.combotab2= ttk.Combobox(self.tabA2)
      self.combotab2.node_id = 'start'
      self.combotab2['values'] = ('a','b','w','x','y','z')
      self.combotab2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.handler15)
      self.combotab2.pack()

      self.combotab22= ttk.Combobox(self.tabA2)
      self.combotab22.node_id = 'end'
      self.combotab22['values'] = ('a','b','w','x','y','z')
      self.combotab22.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.handler215)
      self.combotab22.pack()

    def shortestPath(self,start, end):  # Algorithm
        queue,seen = [(0, start, [])], set()
        while True:
            (cost, v, path) = heapq.heappop(queue)
            if v not in seen:
                path = path + [v]
                seen.add(v)
                if v == end:
                    return cost, path
                for (next, c) in self.graph[v].iteritems():
                    heapq.heappush(queue, (cost + c, next, path))

    graph = {
       'a': {'w': 16, 'x': 9, 'y': 11},
       'b': {'w': 11, 'z': 8},
       'w': {'a': 16, 'b': 11, 'y': 4},
       'x': {'a': 9, 'y': 12, 'z': 17},
       'y': {'a': 11, 'w': 4, 'x': 12, 'z': 13},
       'z': {'b': 8, 'x': 17, 'y': 13},
    }

    def event_handler(self, event, combobox, nodes):

        nodes[combobox.node_id] = combobox.get()
        # call shortestPath() if both a source and destination node are defined
        start, end = nodes.get('start'), nodes.get('end')
        if start and end:
            cost, path = self.shortestPath(start, end)
            print cost, path

    def event_handler2(self,event, combobox, nodes):

        nodes[combobox.node_id] = combobox.get()
        # call shortestPath() if both a source and destination node are defined
        start, end = nodes.get('start'), nodes.get('end')
        if start and end:
            cost, path = self.shortestPath(start, end)
            print cost, path

    def handler1(self,event):  #  interface function
        combobox = self.combo1
        nodes=self.trip
        return self.event_handler(event, combobox, nodes)

    def handler2(self, event):  #  interface function
        combobox = self.combo2
        nodes = self.trip
        return self.event_handler(event, combobox, nodes)

    def handler15(self,event):  #  interface function
        combobox = self.combotab2
        nodes= self.trip
        return self.event_handler2(event, combobox, nodes)

    def handler215(self,  event): #  interface function
        combobox = self.combotab22
        nodes = self.trip
        return self.event_handler2(event, combobox, nodes)

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("400x400")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use one `self.trip` for both tabs. Use `self.trip1` and `self.trip2`.